# Activity behind the passcode is shown in the activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities - one for passcode and the other one behind the passcode activity. The flow is usually when the app is launched the passcode screen/activity is shown first and the main activity is shown next. But, when the app is on the main activity (not the passcode activity), and the app is minimized, the main activity is put in the stack. At this point, if the "recent list" is launched, the main activity is shown, not the passcode activity. Is there any way this can be solved? Or, is this how Android behaves?

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've found that any of the answers below helps you, please click the checkmark to accept it as the answer. This will help people who have the same question find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is how Android behaves, but there may be a solution.

If I understand you correctly, you want the user to always have to enter the passcode before seeing the main screen, whether when launching the app initially, or any time they leave the app and return.

For that, one approach would be to use one `Activity` with two `Fragments`.  Whenever the `Activity` is restarted, load the passcode `Fragment`.  When the correct passcode is entered, switch to the main `Fragment`.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. Your understanding is correct. I have two different activities now. I want the main activity to load only after the passcode is entered, even if it is put into the activity stack and recents is pressed. Does onPause( ) get called when you press recents? If so, can this callback be used to do something?

Comment: If your app is on display and you press recents, your top 
`Activity` will get paused and stopped.  If you're in some other app and you select your app from recents, your top `Activity` will get started and resumed.  If you go with the approach I described, you would want to put the code that displays the passcode `Fragment` in `onStart()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. You can use the following code in the main activity

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    // put your code here...
    this.finish();



}
```

This will remove the main activity fromthe stack every time the app goes in the background.
Also make sure that you don't finish() the Passcode Activity when you startActivity to the main activity.

eg: (in your Passcode Activity)

```
Intent i  = new Intent(PasscodeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: With this approach, the PasscodeActivity would be in the backstack when the MainActivity is on top, meaning that hitting the back button from the MainActivity would redisplay the PasscodeActivity, rather than exiting the app.

Comment: Well, if you don't want this to happen then just override the OnBackPressed method and call the finishAffinity() 

@Override 
public void onBackPressed() 
{
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        this.finishAffinity(); }

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so... How about launching the passcode activity? Then from there you'd be able to launch the main activity, and finish the passcode activity. This way the main activity isn't launched until the passcode is actually entered, and it'll help you keep the responsibilities separated. Seems like the easiest solution to me.

Comment: This could work, although it creates kind of a circular relationship between the two activities.  With this approach, you'd want to set a flag in MainActivity's onStop() that meant "start PasscodeActivity and finish me the next time onStart() is called".  Or, I suppose you could just do that in onStop directly.

Comment: @AndyDennie Does it? Yes, they both call each other, but so do they in the current approach. This way you can just set a flag "isLoggedIn" and have the mainActivity check for that flag. If it's not there, it stops itself after starting the PasscodeActivity. Not a whole lot more circularity there than in the current approach, from my point of view.

Comment: As I understood the original question, the PasscodeActivity started the MainActivity, but not the other way around.  But as I said, your approach works.

Comment: Sorry guys. I was out of town and didn't track the responses till this week. I  just started reading all the responses. I shall post what I tried later. Thank you all for responding